# Regex expressions help - query strings

Tags: regex, query-string

Can anyone give me the regex to validate the URL with the query string with 2 parameters

```
http://www.example.com?pid=3&sid=4
```

I want to validate if the input matches the above URL with exact parameters, how do i write a regex for this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just compare two strings? Why would you need a Regex to do an _exact_ match?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(http://)?(www\.)?[0-9A-z]+\.com\?pid=(?<pid>\d+)&sid=(?<sid>\d+)$
```

Comment: This wouldnt match the url if it had a trailing slash, i.e. `http://www.abc.com/?pid=3&sid=4`, nor would it match `https`. Not sure if those are requirements.

Comment: @Jeff for https and trailing slash: `^(https?://)?(www\.)?[0-9A-z]+\.com/?\?pid=(?<pid>\d+)&sid=(?<sid>\d+)$`

Comment: Thank you for the response, my actual requiremnet is http://www.abc.com/test/default.aspx?tid=1&sid=2 - here the paramter values are exact numbers - so i have changed the regex above to "^(http://)?(www\.)?[0-9A-z]+\[0-9A-z]+\.com\?tid=1+&sid=2+$" - but it didnot work, can you tell me the corrections..

Comment: `^(https?://)?(www\.)?[0-9A-z]+\.com/[0-9A-z]+/[0-9A-z]+\.aspx\?pid=(?<pid>\d+)&sid=(?<sid>\d+)$` will match `abc.com/test/default.aspx?pid=1&sid=2`

Answer (score 1):

```
^https?://(www\.)?((?!-)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-)\.)+\w{2,6}/\w+/(default\.aspx)?\?pid=\d+&sid=\d+$
```

Will match:

```
http://www.domain.tld/directory/?pid=123&sid=123
http://www.domain.tld/directory/default.aspx?pid=123&sid=123
http://www.sub-domain.domain.tld/directory/?pid=123&sid=123
http://www.sub-domain.domain.tld/directory/default.aspx?pid=123&sid=123
```

as well as URLs without `www.` and URLs with https as protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **pid** & **sid** are static.

```
pid=(.*)&sid=(.*)
```